# Using a WeakReference Context with SQLiteOpenHelper inside class extending AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, weak-references, sqliteopenhelper

I am passing a Context reference from the calling Activity to an AsyncTask file that handles all my SQLite database transactions. I discovered the following warnings in LogCat:

> W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database 'grocery_database' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
>   W/System: A resource failed to call close.

I read that using a weak reference to the Context is preferable because it allows the current AsyncTask to be garbage collected and prevent memory leaks. However, the SQLiteOpenHelper I am using will not accept a weak reference to a Context.

```
public class UpdateDatabaseTask extends AsyncTask <Long, Void, Void>{

  private long listItemId;
  private String userInput;
  private WeakReference<Context> weakContext;
  private SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper;

  public UpdateDatabaseTask(Context context, String userInput) {

    weakContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
    this.userInput = userInput;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Long... listItemIdArray) {

    listItemId = listItemIdArray[0];

    // SQLiteOpenHelper does not accept a weak reference
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(weakContext);
  }
```

Now Android Studio shows the following error:
[image]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: WeakReference just to mark your context to weak reference which will be clear by Garbage Collector  to not hold the reference of AsyncTask to the destroyed context -> avoid Memory leak.so just change to the answer below

Comment: Initialize Singleton SQLiteOpenHelper inside Application to avoid memory leak.

Comment: @shadow I don't understand your solution. Could you please clarify?

Comment: you dont pass the weak reference you need to "get" the item that is being weakreferenced...so should be able to just weakContext.get()